# Working on a project w/ NBA data & would like to change the all the columns except a specific three to a numeric datatype using .ne() or other method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, types

```
url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1986_totals.html'

eightyfive = pd.read_html(url)[0]

# removing rows with no values but are just labels
eightyfive = eightyfive[eightyfive['Rk'].ne('Rk')]

# creating a copy to avoid error from assignment
eightyfive = eightyfive.copy()


eightyfive = eightyfive.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1).ne(['Player','Pos','Tm'], axis=1)
eightyfive
```

I've tried putting the three columns I **don't** want to change *into* a numeric type into a list and running this list through a for loop.

I've tried removing `errors` from `apply`

Whatever I've tried I usually end up with a `ValueError` or a `KeyError`.
Sometimes I'll get a parsing error. I can't recall it specifically for now but it will say something along the lines of *"Cannot parse Kareem-Abdul Jabar at position 0"*

I'm not beholden to using `ne()` but I just stumbled upon it today and would like to use it. I do, however, want to know how to change the datatype for the dataframe to a numeric **except** a specific three columns. I have to cover about 35+ years of data and want to just apply this change to all of the dataframes in one fell swoop( I plan on putting the dataframes into a dictionary and then changing the datatypes en masse)

This is the dataframe I'm working with. [image]

The last column is 'PTS' and it stands for points. I want to run various equations on the columns so I need them to be numeric. A few of the columns are to the third decimal place and I do want to retain that as well for accuracy as opposed to them being round to the hundredths place.

Comment: Mate, I tried but everything gives me back error as well. astype or to_numeric is not working. I'm bookmarking this one. Good luck!!

Comment: Some people will crucify me, but maybe this is an easy job in excel. lol

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the columns you want to change:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1986_totals.html'

eightyfive = pd.read_html(url)[0]

# removing rows with no values but are just labels
eightyfive = eightyfive[eightyfive['Rk'].ne('Rk')]

# creating a copy to avoid error from assignment
eightyfive = eightyfive.copy()

numeric_cols = [x for x in eightyfive.columns if x not in ['Player','Pos','Tm']]
for col in numeric_cols:
    eightyfive[col] = pd.to_numeric(eightyfive[col])
```

OR

Use the try/except and it'll convert any that it can without declaring specific columns:

```
for col in eightyfive.columns:
    try:
        eightyfive[col] = pd.to_numeric(eightyfive[col])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**Output:**

```
eightyfive.dtypes
Out[6]: 
Rk          int64
Player     object
Pos        object
Age         int64
Tm         object
G           int64
GS          int64
MP          int64
FG          int64
FGA         int64
FG%       float64
3P          int64
3PA         int64
3P%       float64
2P          int64
2PA         int64
2P%       float64
eFG%      float64
FT          int64
FTA         int64
FT%       float64
ORB         int64
DRB         int64
TRB         int64
AST         int64
STL         int64
BLK         int64
TOV         int64
PF          int64
PTS         int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you! I was just working on this one!

Comment: I like the Try and Except alternative to. I'm not versed on how use it but this makes a lot of sense. Thank you @chitown88